# How can I change anaconda's python version to 3.3 from 3.4

Tags: anaconda, matplotlib-basemap

I've been used anaconda for 2 months and it's fantastic tool for me.

At first, I'd started with anaconda 2 (w/ python 2.7) but I changed to the latest version, which has python 3.4 and currently my anaconda version is 2.2.0.

And, because I should install basemap library I [googled](https://twitter.com/continuumio/status/410157916524539904') and found the answer that anaconda can support basemap using it's conda tool.

But, when I finished conda install basemap, I saw the messssage that conflict occured with python 3.4 like below.

```
Fetching package metadata: Could not connect to https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/win-64/
Could not connect to https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/win-64/
Could not connect to https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/noarch/
.Could not connect to https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/noarch/
...
Solving package specifications: ..
Error: Unsatisfiable package specifications.
Generating hint:
[      COMPLETE      ] |#################################################| 100%


Hint: the following combinations of packages create a conflict with the
remaining packages:
  - python 3.4*
  - basemap
```

I understand this message as I should change my python version. Is it right? If so, how can I chnage, I mean downgrade from 3.4 to 3.3?
If not, why installation failed?

Comment: I can `conda install basemap` with Python 3.4 OK. If it's still failing for you, ask about it on the [Anaconda mailing list](https://groups.google.com/a/continuum.io/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/anaconda), or [file an issue](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues).

Answer (score 2):

Getting a specific version of Python, or a package, is very easy in Anaconda. Anaconda allows you to create environments where you can have specific versions separated from each other.

```
conda create -n py33 python=3.3 basemap
```

The above will create an environment with python 3.3, basemap, and any dependencies needed. The format is to specify a name after the -n(I used py33) and specify the version after the package with an equals sign. Then to use this environment you simply activate it as follows:

Windows:

```
source py33
```

Mac OS X/Linux:

```
source activate py33
```

Answer (score 1):

Per [docs](http://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/pkg-docs), `basemap` is *only* available for Python 2.7 on windows OS. For Unix systems it's available for Python 2.6, 2.7, 3.3 and 3.4.

The conflict occurs when you you have Python 3.x on windows and you try to install Basemap through `conda install basemap`.

Here's `conda info basemap` output specifically listing the dependencies for the variant versions of `numpy`.

```
C:\Anaconda3>conda info basemap
Fetching package metadata: ....

basemap 1.0.7 np19py27_0
------------------------
file name   : basemap-1.0.7-np19py27_0.tar.bz2
name        : basemap
version     : 1.0.7
build number: 0
build string: np19py27_0
channel     : defaults
size        : 120.5 MB
date        : 2014-09-09
license     : PSF
md5         : 18142d0b3ede8b156f31c627d78aea72
installed environments:
dependencies:
    matplotlib
    numpy 1.9*
    python 2.7*

basemap 1.0.7 np18py27_0
------------------------
file name   : basemap-1.0.7-np18py27_0.tar.bz2
name        : basemap
version     : 1.0.7
build number: 0
build string: np18py27_0
channel     : defaults
size        : 120.5 MB
date        : 2014-08-22
license     : PSF
md5         : 14cabc1a134b14073fe3afa943753888
installed environments:
dependencies:
    matplotlib
    numpy 1.8*
    python 2.7*

basemap 1.0.7 np17py27_0
------------------------
file name   : basemap-1.0.7-np17py27_0.tar.bz2
name        : basemap
version     : 1.0.7
build number: 0
build string: np17py27_0
channel     : defaults
size        : 120.5 MB
date        : 2014-08-22
license     : PSF
md5         : 6bcb42a4435836b342c96d94a98ef785
installed environments:
dependencies:
    matplotlib
    numpy 1.7*
    python 2.7*

basemap 1.0.7 np110py27_0
-------------------------
file name   : basemap-1.0.7-np110py27_0.tar.bz2
name        : basemap
version     : 1.0.7
build number: 0
build string: np110py27_0
channel     : defaults
size        : 120.5 MB
date        : 2015-10-06
license     : PSF
md5         : e451471ff2a2ccdbf09e81c61cc103bb
installed environments:
dependencies:
    matplotlib
    numpy 1.10*
    python 2.7*
```

Answer (score 0):

The anaconda install doesn't work with Python 3 right now so going from 3.4 to 3.3 won't help you. Here is what I had to do to get basemap with anaconda (on Windows):

1. Create a new environment with the latest version of Python 2

   ```
   conda create --name py2 python=2.7
   ```
2. Change to that environment:

   ```
   activate py2
   ```
3. Install basemap:

   ```
   conda install -c https://conda.anaconda.org/anaconda basemap
   ```